# MOUSE_OUT Triggered immediately after MOUSE_OVER, even if still on button

Tags: actionscript-3, simplebutton

So like the title says, I have an overly-simple button (code below) that I can't see any obvious reason why it wouldn't work. When the mouse is over the button, it should proceed to the "over" state, and when the mouse is off again it should display the "normal" stage. Nothing fancy, but any time I roll over the button, I receive both trace messages within a second of each other (without my cursor coming off of the button).

I've also tried `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER`, `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT` with the same results.

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip; 
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class thisShouldWork extends MovieClip{

        public function thisShouldWork() {
            mouseChildren = false;
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, handleMouseRollOver, false, 0, true);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, handleMouseRollOut, false, 0, true);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleMouseDown, false, 0, true);
        }

        protected function handleMouseRollOver(event:MouseEvent):void{
            trace("OVER" + event.currentTarget);
            gotoAndStop("over");
        }
        protected function handleMouseRollOut(event:MouseEvent):void{
            trace("NORMAL");
            gotoAndStop("normal");
        }
        protected function handleMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void{
            trace("DOWN");
            gotoAndStop("down");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how does your button look like? are there any "holes" in it?

Comment: it's just a solid triangle BMP that's been changed into a movie clip. When I resize the button to be a crazy large size, I still have the same problem